# WTForms-prepopulate a textarea field with a string value?

Tags: python, html, class, flask, wtforms

I'm trying to pepopulate a wtforms-textareafield with a value.

I defined a class:

```
from flask_wtf import Form
from wtforms import TextField, RadioField, TextAreaField

class Contact(Form):
    email = TextField('Name : ')
    subject = TextField('Subject:')
    description = TextAreaField('Description:', default="please add content")
```

I'm using python, here i render template :

```
from app.mod_contact.contact import Contact
//some code
contact = Contact()
return render_template('contact/contact.html')
```

In template i did this:

```
<div class="form-group">
      {{ contact.description.label(class_="control-label col-xs-3") }}
       <div class="col-xs-6">
           {{ contact.description(class_="form-control")}}  
       </div>
</div>
```

But the default text is not displayed,it's blank.

I also tried to add value on template:

```
{{ contact.description(class_="form-control" ,value="please type content")}}
```

But no result. Can somebody help me? Thanks in advance.

Comment: I checked this on my `Flask` instance and it works OK with `default` keyword. I assume your problem might be somewhere in re-defining field `description`.

Comment: @wanderlust i tried redefining but still the same problem, do u have any other idea?

Comment: can you put full snipet for class declaration and initialization as well?

Comment: @wanderlust i edited my question :)

Answer (score 1):

I tried to repeat your steps, so please find following code complete:

**test.py** (start code)

```
from wtforms import TextField, RadioField, TextAreaField

class Contact(Form):
    email = TextField('Name : ')
    subject = TextField('Subject:')
    description = TextAreaField('Description:', default="please add content")

app = Flask(__name__)
app.secret_key = 'A0Zr98j/3yX R~XHH!jmN]LWX/,?RT'

@app.route('/test')
def test():
    contact = Contact()
    return render_template('contact/contact.html', contact=contact)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(debug=True)
```

**contact/contact.html**

```
<html>
  <body>
    <div class="form-group">
          {{ contact.description.label(class_="control-label col-xs-3") }}
          <div class="col-xs-6">
              {{ contact.description(class_="form-control")}}  
          </div>
    </div> 
</body>
</html>
```

Project tree is as follows:

```
.
├── templates
│   └── contact
│       └── contact.html
└── test.py
```

As you may see from the given code, you should pass instance of class `Contact` as extra parameter to `render_template`. I didn't see this in your code, so I assume you missed it. In such case you should be able to see rendered TextAreaField also, but you mentioned you see it, but you don't see default value. In this snippet everything works.

P.S. I assume, you would like that message "please add content" automatically disappear when user types something. For this purpose you should update following line in the `contect.html` in such manner:

```
{{ contact.description(class_="form-control", placeholder="please add content")}}
```

Comment: I didn't copied right because parameter  contact=contact in my form. I don't know why is not working still..anyway thank you for ur answer.

Comment: Try with the above code, and then extend it to your needs.

Comment: i notice an weird thing , if i do an inspect element on textareafield it has a string value, but  that value is not  appeared in page ?